# Xamarin.Forms iOS application crash on release after SplashScreen

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash

I have a very bad issue right now:

Behavior:

[image: Setup]

**Application work when debug, but in release exit when app start.**

The debugg information is not clear for the reason the application fail only in release mode.

1. Visual Studio 2019
2. Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1821
3. ZxIng.Net.Mobile 2.4.1
4. ZxIng.Net.Mobile.Forms 2.4.1
5. Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3
6. Xamarin.Essentials 1.6.1
7. SDK 14.4

Simulator log file:

```
Process:              myapp-ui.iOS [19566]

Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2C19C42D-564E-42CB-B805-C9C49BB1E8FD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1F644647-27DB-48EF-96D6-75A169AE4E9D/myapp-ui.iOS.app/myapp-ui.iOS

Identifier:            myapp-ui.iOS

Version:               2.0.3 (1610484945)

Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)

Parent Process:        launchd_sim [17405]

Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [1267]

User ID:               501


Date/Time:             2021-02-16 12:29:44.629 -0600

OS Version:            macOS 11.2.1 (20D74)

Report Version:        12

Anonymous UUID:        E13D7872-1C1C-3306-5557-E45B4D68317D



Time Awake Since Boot: 350000 seconds


System Integrity Protection: enabled


Crashed Thread:        0  tid_307  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread


Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY


Application Specific Information:

abort() called

CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro (2C19C42D-564E-42CB-B805-C9C49BB1E8FD) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro


Thread 0 Crashed:: tid_307  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff61131462 __pthread_kill + 10

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6116a610 pthread_kill + 263

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff200fac2e __abort + 139

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff200faba3 abort + 135

4   io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001045caa6f xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler + 31 (runtime.m:1151)

5   io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x000000010445f415 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 133 (exception.c:1265)

6   io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x000000010439ce2a mono_handle_exception_internal + 6986 (mini-exceptions.c:2782)

7   io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x000000010439b2d9 mono_handle_exception + 25 (mini-exceptions.c:3107)

8   io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x000000010431b969 mono_amd64_throw_exception + 169 (exceptions-amd64.c:409)

9   ???                             0x0000000104f6a5b0 0 + 4378240432

10  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001045ca7ed xamarin_process_managed_exception + 301 (runtime.m:2356)

11  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001045d1482 xamarin_invoke_trampoline + 1250 (trampolines-invoke.m:686)

12  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001045d3642 xamarin_arch_trampoline + 82 (trampolines-x86_64.m:491)

13  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001045d400a xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline + 118 (trampolines-x86_64-asm.s:51)

14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff208592ba __NSThreadPerformPerform + 204

15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2039038a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17

16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20390282 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180

17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2038f7c6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 346

18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20389f2f __CFRunLoopRun + 878

19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff203896d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567

20  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x00007fff2c257db3 GSEventRunModal + 139

21  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00007fff24696cf7 -[UIApplication _run] + 912

22  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00007fff2469bba8 UIApplicationMain + 101

23  ???                             0x00000001065cb0a4 0 + 4401705124

24  ???                             0x00000001065caf13 0 + 4401704723

25  ???                             0x00000001065c7313 0 + 4401689363

26  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001043b36d1 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1569 (mini-runtime.c:3191)

27  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001044d9c08 do_runtime_invoke + 54 (object.c:3052) [inlined]

28  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001044d9c08 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136 (object.c:3220)

29  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001044dff75 do_exec_main_checked + 60 [inlined]

30  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001044dff75 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 117 (object.c:5284)

31  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001043124ec mono_jit_exec_internal + 14 (driver.c:1383) [inlined]

32  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001043124ec mono_jit_exec + 364 (driver.c:1328)

33  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001045d3196 xamarin_main + 1686 (monotouch-main.m:493)

34  io.myapp.myapp-easyapp              0x00000001042cc857 main + 55 (main.m:55)

35  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2025a3e9 start + 1
```

Comment: Enable debugging in the release configuration and figure out for yourself what is going on

Comment: Try without any linking behavior

Comment: @Cheesebaron sorry but I write it already, the error do not reproduce in debug mode, only release, it was to do with Entitlement.plist file after several hours of investigation, but now is happens in the shop testflight version only.

Comment: I am telling you to enable debug in the release mode configuration, or change your debug config to match release, except for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately the problem is Entitlement.plist, for some reason when use SecureStorage from Xamarin.Essentials, the application crash in release Testflight on shop, so I remove SecureStorage and problem solved.

Thanks all for all the answers.

Comment: Yes you need the keychain entitlements when using keychain access through essentials for iOS simulator. However, you shouldn't have this prob on devices as it is not needed. You could always check the logcat output in release, local or from testflight. There you should have some clues.

Comment: Glad you have solved that, remember to mark the answer when you have time.